# rpm-maven-plugin v2.1.5 automatically gzipping my file

Tags: maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I have a man file that I want installed to /usr/share/man/man8 during the rpm install. This is my mapping.

```
<mapping>
  <directory>/usr/share/man/man8</directory>
  <documentation>true</documentation> <!-- no difference if I add or remove this -->
  <filemode>644</filemode>
  <username>root</username>
  <groupname>root</groupname>
  <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
  <recurseDirectories>false</recurseDirectories>
  <sources>
    <source>
      <location>${project.build.directory}</location>
      <includes>
        <include>mymanpage.8</include>
      </includes>
    </source>
  </sources>
</mapping>
```

rpm-maven-plugin errors and tells me **mymanpage.8** is not found. I verified that **mymanpage.8** is in the target directory. Then I noticed that the plugin copied **mymanpage.8.gz** to the **target/rpm/rpmtest/buildroot/usr/share/man/man8** directory. So I'm assuming the plugin recognized somehow that it can gzip this man page and did it but since my mapping is specifically including mymanpage.8 it complains it cannot find it. I tried changing the include to mymanpage.8* and it still gives me the same file not found error.

Has anyone seen this before? What's the fix?

I guess I have a workaround which is to copy the mymanpage.8 file to my install directory and then in the postinstall scriptlet move it to /usr/share/man/man8.

Answer (score 0):

The rpm-maven-plugin delegates the work to the rpmbuild command.
This ones compress the man pages for you.

You can use the `location` tag to specify a directory but also a file.

```
<mapping>
  <directory>/usr/share/man/man8</directory>
  <filemode>644</filemode>
  <username>root</username>
  <groupname>root</groupname>
  <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
  <recurseDirectories>false</recurseDirectories>
  <sources>
    <source>
      <location>${project.build.directory}/mymanpage.8</location>
    </source>
  </sources>
</mapping>
```

If you prefer to use includes, you must use wildcard pattern.

The `documentation` tag is not intended for manpages but for other documentation as changelogs for example. See [rpm-maven-plugin documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/map-params.html#documentation).

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that the man page is built in a later phase than package. So when the rpm plugin is trying to package the man page it is not there yet. You can find the life cycles here:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

So make sure the man page is created and end up in build directory before package phase like in generate-resources for example.

Answer (score 0):

Before rpm packaging, there are man pages with ".8" extension. `Rpmbuild` compresses man pages forcibly and renames them with .gz extension, so `rpm-maven-plugin` can't find files with ".8" extension. The first solution is just to rename uncompressed files with .gz extension like this

```
<mapping>
    <directory>/usr/share/man/man8</directory>
    <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded><!-- required for CentOS 7 -->
    <sources>
        <source>
            <!-- rpmbuild rename manpages from *.8 to *.8.gz, so we should use <destination> tag to set new name -->
            <location>generated-docs/mymanpage.8</location>
            <destination>mymanpage.8.gz</destination>
        </source>
    </sources>
<mapping>
```

Now `rpmbuild` doesn't rename file anymore and it works for CentOS 7 (which uses man-db package for working with manpages), but does not work for CentOS 6 (which uses man package for working with manpages), CentOS 6 can't open such man pages.

So for fixing, man pages manually compressing required. For compressing you can use [resourcecompressor](https://github.com/RyanHoldren/ResourceCompressor) maven plugin for example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.ryanholdren</groupId>
    <artifactId>resourcecompressor</artifactId>
    <version>2017-06-24</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <directory>generated-docs/</directory>
                <filter>\.8$</filter>
                <compression>SMALLEST</compression>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now, `rpm-maven-plugin` may be configured to use `.gz` files (and wildcard expression can be used, if need) and `rpmbuild` doesn't try to rename and compress man pages.

```
<mapping>
    <directory>/usr/share/man/man8</directory>
    <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded><!-- required for CentOS 7 -->
    <sources>
        <source>
            <location>generated-docs/</location>
            <includes>
                <include>*.8.gz</include>
            </includes>
        </source>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```